# Visual Studio Team Services - FTP Publish

Tags: visual-studio, ftp, azure-devops, continuous-deployment

Visual Studio Team Services has interesting features like GIT storage and automated building triggered by GIT Commit. I'm trying to use the repository to keep static HTML site files and autobuild to publish files on hosting. Unfortunately the hosting doesn't support any publish way except of FTP connection.

Is it possible to use VSTS autobuild to publish entire site (with set of sub-folders) using FTP connection?

"cURL Upload Files" step supports FTP but it can't create folders structure automatically.

I believe that either "Batch Script" or "Powershell" or "Command line" task can help somehow but stuck with exact implementation :(

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can install [FTP Uploader](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=januskamphansen.ftpupload-task) extension and then add this task in your build definition to publish files to FTP server.

Comment: Thanks a lot! It is exactly what I need!